# Use variable in src in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, src

I am creating a table and then in every row of table I need to put different image depending on the results retrieved from the database.

`ImageVariable=Image1.jpg`

```
<"Table>
    <"TR> 
    <"TD>
        <"IMG SRC=<%=ImageVariable %>> 
    <"/td>
    <"/tr>
<"/table>
```

However, when I view the results, this image variable is not converted to the actual value but is considered as value itself, so my image link becomes `htt://Ritesh/Imagevariable`

Instead what I want is `htt://Ritesh/Image1.jpg`

Please assist.

Comment: What's with all of the quotes inside your markup?, e.g. `<"Table>`?

Answer (score 1):

Do some thing like this.

```
public static string ImageVariable="Image1.jpg"
```

then write in <%=%> block